# error messages for missing arguments for ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-histogram

```
Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(diff(sort(x))) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: Removed 7687 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_count()`).
```

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart of influenza serotypes by month and I cannot get past this error message because I am unsure as to what I am missing.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

Sys.setenv(TZ="America/New_York")
today <- Sys.Date()

flu2018_file <- "2018_flu.txt"
df_flu2018 <- as.data.frame(read.table(flu2018_file, sep="\t", header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE, fill=TRUE))

df_flu2018$month <- floor_date(as_date(mdy(df_flu2018$date)), unit="month")

plot_1 <- ggplot(df_flu2018) + 
     geom_histogram(stat="count", aes(x = month, fill = serotype)) 

plot_1
```

below is the output for dput(head(df_flu2018))

```
df_flu2018 <- structure(list(accession = c("MH083301", "MH083303", "MH083309", 
"MH083311", "MH081888", "MH081892"), length = c(1752L, 1433L, 
1752L, 1433L, 1441L, 1737L), host = c("Human", "Human", "Human", 
"Human", "Human", "Human"), segment = c("4 (HA)", "6 (NA)", "4 (HA)", 
"6 (NA)", "6 (NA)", "4 (HA)"), serotype = c("H1N1", "H1N1", "H1N1", 
"H1N1", "H3N2", "H3N2"), country = c("USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA"), region = c("N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N"), date = c("2018/01/02", 
"2018/01/02", "2018/01/03", "2018/01/03", "2018/01/03", "2018/01/03"
), name = c("Influenza A virus (A/Alabama/01/2018(H1N1))", "Influenza A virus (A/Alabama/01/2018(H1N1))", 
"Influenza A virus (A/Alabama/02/2018(H1N1))", "Influenza A virus (A/Alabama/02/2018(H1N1))", 
"Influenza A virus (A/Alabama/03/2018(H3N2))", "Influenza A virus (A/Alabama/03/2018(H3N2))"
), mutations = c("", "", "", "", "", ""), age = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), gender = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), lineage = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), vac_strain = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    fulllength_plus = c("c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"), month = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput(df_flu2018)` to make your issue reproducible.

Comment: As an aside, there's no need to load dplyr, ggplot2 and lubridate after loading the tidyverse package, as they are all included in the tidyverse set.

Comment: Please run `dput(head(df_flu2018))` and paste the output into your question. That will create a code recipe to recreate the first 6 rows of the data frame, including the data formats and structure.

Comment: As another aside, there is no need for `as.data.frame` after `read.table` - the latter should return a data frame. Your code to generate a month from the date also looks incorrect, and for a stacked bar chart you should be using `geom_col` not `geom_histogram`.

Comment: hi! welcome to stack overflow Sarah. I was wondering, is your data in YMD or YDM format? It's impossible to say from what you've shown

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when creating your dates you use `mdy()` which requires dates in the format "Month-Day-Year" whereas the data column in your dataset  is in the format `YYYY-DD-MM` or `YYYY-MM-DD`, i.e. the year comes first. As a result you end up with a `month` vector of `NA`s or missings which results in the error *no non-missing arguments*:

```
df_flu2018$month <- floor_date(
  mdy(df_flu2018$date),
  unit = "month"
)
#> Warning: All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

df_flu2018$month
#> [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

To fix that use the right conversion function, i.e. `ymd()` or `ydm()`, e.g. assuming that your dates are in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)

df_flu2018$month <- floor_date(
  ymd(df_flu2018$date),
  unit = "month"
)

ggplot(df_flu2018) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = month, fill = serotype))
```

[image]